# Netdom computername /Add returns "The request is not supported"

Tags: windows-7, dns, windows-10

I'm running into an issue on Windows 7 and Windows 10 when running the following:

```
netdom computername %computername% /Add:%computername%.ourDomainName.NET
```

The response I get is: "The request is not supported".

I'm running this against a machine on AWS that is joined to its own local Workgroup.  The machine is connected to our on-premise network via a VPN.  This request works fine on Windows 2012 for a machine on the same subnet configured in the same way.

Some potentially unnecessary context: We run this command so that the DNS suffix is the same before and after joining our domain, which is done via chef.  However, before we register the chef node, we must set the DNS suffix to be its permanent value, or chef will lose the connection after it joins the machine to the domain.  This is why we run netdom computername /add before joining the domain via chef.

I have found references as to why netdom renamecomputer would return "The request is not supported" (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725669(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_Rename).  However, I can't find a reason as to why computername /add would throw this error.

I see nothing that appears to be related in the Windows\debug\NetSetup.log (nothing is logged there when I run the command).

Does anyone know where this logs/how to start troubleshooting this, or what might be going wrong?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact same problem.  This can be caused by not deleting the original computer name and waiting for replication so that the record is cleared from DNS before it can be added again.